# How can I set default parameter value for an action in struts-config.xml?

Tags: struts, parameter-passing, default

How can I set default parameter value for an action in struts-config.xml?

Such as:

```
if action path="stamp" and parameter="language" ->
```

the user can hit

```
url <context-path>/stamp.do
```

where in some default value is used such as 'en' for language parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done this. Doing some quick research, you can do it by using the dynamic action form. You specify within your form beans the attributes of your forms and their initial values, then you use it as a normal form. An example is found here:

[building controller components](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/userGuide/building_controller.html)

in the 4.3.1 section